# Windows 8 boot failure since Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I have had Ubuntu 11.10 installed on my computer on one hard disk. On another disk, there is Windows 8 Consumer Preview. I've been able to dual-boot with my BIOS's HDD selector. When I updated my Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, it included the new version of GRUB, which had an entry for Windows 8, as expected.

However, whenever I try to boot into Windows 8, I can see the fish for a second or two and then a few lines of error code as follows:

```
Your computer needs to restart. Please hold down the power button. Error code: 0x00000050 Parameters: 0xFFFFFAB006800000 0X0000000000000000 0XFFFFF801D09B6C90 0X0000000000000002
```

Can anyone help me chainload the Windows MBR to GRUB correctly to avoid a boot problem, or suggest a new bootloader to replace (or run along side of) GRUB so I can boot Windows 8 without problems?

Comment: sorry for lack of image...

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the following command in the Terminal: `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: i ran `sudo update-grub` and it loaded everything, but when i restarted, i ran into the same scenario. it gave me the fish image and then flashed an error code. i should have listed it, but it is as follows:  **your computer needs to restart.  please hold down the power button.  error code: 0x00000050  Parameters: 0xFFFFFAB006800000  0X0000000000000000  0XFFFFF801D09B6C90  0X0000000000000002**

Answer (score 1):

I doubt updating grub will work if it stays at default. However, if you can see the beta fish, after grub, it sounds like the problem may lie in the windows MBR.

You may want to try to restore the MBR by booting from a pendrive with Windows 8 installer on it (as you would with a Ubuntu live cd). Instead of installing, select the repair option in the bottom left corner. From there, you can attempt an automatic repair or reset your Windows install. Just make sure not to erase your data. I have had a lot of odd problems with Windows 8 myself. Then again I do mess around with the registries a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu using a live cd or usb and download boot-repair by going here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

This will take care of most problems automatically. BTW I had this same issue when updating to 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for quite some time and it certainly tested my patience until I resolved it by pure luck.

Just install grub on the hard disk where your Windows 8 partition lies and change your BIOS settings so that this disk boots first.

I hope this saves some people the trouble I went through to get this sorted out.